# Cómo referenciar a una columna de una clave compuesta de una tabla en ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo una tabla (COFRE) cuya clave primaria es compuesta por las columnas cof_id y ava_id.
Y quiero que otra tabla llamada CODRE_PRODUCTO, una columna haga referencia a la columna cof_id de la tabla COFRE, pero me sale el siguiente error:

```
ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
```

No entiendo cómo hacer. Aquí les dejo el código:

```
CREATE TABLE COFRE(
    cof_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ava_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT cof_pk PRIMARY KEY (cof_id, ava_id),
    CONSTRAINT cof_ava_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (ava_id) REFERENCES AVATAR(ava_id)
);

CREATE TABLE COFRE_PRODUCTO(
    cof_id NUMBER,
    pro_id NUMBER,
    CONSTRAINT cof_pro_pk PRIMARY KEY (cof_id, pro_id),
    CONSTRAINT cof_pro_cof_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (cof_id) REFERENCES COFRE(cof_id),
    CONSTRAINT cof_pro_pro_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (pro_id) REFERENCES PRODUCTO(pro_id)
);
```

Creo que el error está en el CONSTRAINT cof_pro_cof_id_fk de la tabla COFRE_PRODUCTO porque referencia a la columna cof_id, y cof_id no es una clave primaria, pero forma parte de una clave primaria compuesta

Comment: Las foreign keys deben usar LA PRIMARY KEY. No una parte, no una de las columnas. TODA la PK.

Comment: NO entiendo muy bien porque en una tabla que ya tiene su propio id, intentas que parte de su key sea una foranea, cuadno entiendo que la entidad cofre ya tiene significado por sí misma, te recomendaría mirarte [Normalización de Bases de Datos](https://guru99.es/database-normalization/) ya que tu base de datos no está normalizada, si una entidad tiene sentido por sí misma, no entiendo que tenga FK como parte de su PK, al menos en una base de datos relacional... esto no tiene sentido